# Calling listener from another form

Tags: c#, listener

My main form shows some info, and that same info can be edited in second form. Info in main page is loaded (to DGV) from database and it loads when TabControl listener is triggered. In the second form I have the button that changes that info in database, and when I change it, my main form is showing wrong info until I actually trigger that TabControl listener myself. How should I make that TabControl listener calls automatically when I click button in second form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second form is a popup dialog that will be completed and then closed, you can do it like this:

```
SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm();
secondForm.ShowDialog();

// ShowDialog will block until the new form is closed.

RefreshData(); // we know that the user is done with the second form, so we can check for changes here.
```

Otherwise, you can pass in a reference to your parent form, and update it from the child form as needed.  In your parent form:

```
SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm(this); // pass a reference to the parent form into the child form's constructor
secondForm.Show(); // unlike ShowDialog(), Show() will not block the parent form.  The user can use both forms at the same time.
```

and then in your child form:

```
FirstForm ParentForm { get; set; }

public SecondForm(FirstForm parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ParentForm = parent; // store the reference for later use
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ParentForm.Name = txtName.Text; // set a public property on the parent form
    ParentForm.Address = txtAddress.Text;

}
```

Comment: The second suggestion was better because I wanted to be able to use both forms in the same time